# Probability problem regarding coin toss

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

A coin is tossed repeatedly. If a head turns up, the player gets $1$ point; if a tail turns up, the player gets $2$ points. What is the probability that the player gets a total of exactly $n$ points?

> My attempt:
>          I tried to partition $n$ by $1$′s & $2$′s . Thus if $n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, there are either $k$ number of $2$′s & $0$ number of $1$′s
>   or $(k−2)$ number of $2$′s & $2$ number of $1$′s or etc. So the number
>   of possible cases is 
>   $\binom{2k}{k}\cdot\binom{2k}{0}+\binom{2k}{k-1}\cdot\binom{2k}{2}+⋯+\binom{2k}{0}\cdot\binom{2k}{2k}$.
>   Thus the probability of obtaining one of the possible cases is 
>   $\dfrac{1}{\binom{2k}{k}+\binom{2k}{k-1}⋅\binom{2k}{2}+⋯+\binom{2k}{0}⋅\binom{2k}{2k}}$.
>   Similarly, if $n=2k−1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ then the number of possible
>   cases can be evaluated.
>
> The answer in the book is
>   $\dfrac12+\dfrac16\left(1−\left(−\dfrac12\right)^{n−1}\right)$.
>
> Does the expression I've evaluated simplifies to this answer after
>   some algebraic computations or am I in a completely wrong direction?

Comment: Hint:  work recursively.  Let $P(n)$ be the answer, find a recursion connecting $P(n)$ to $P(n-1),P(n-2)$.

Comment: I assume the coin is tossed more than $n$ times

Comment: But what's the problem with my method?

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee, I think you meant $(k - 1)$ $2$s and $2$ $1$s in your previous comment?

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee: As it stands, your question lacks context, though you have added it in a comment. Your first comment should really be edited into your question.

Comment: Since you are asking probability, we need to know how many tosses are made, or are you asking what is the probability of getting exactly $n$ at *any* point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the last throw in a successful series. Player had either $n-1$ points and threw head, or had $n-2$ points and threw tails. So, the probability:
$$
p_n = \frac12p_{n-1}+\frac12 p_{n-2}
$$

We solve this recursive equation by assuming $p_n = z^n$ and fidning eigenvalues $z_1=1$, $z_2=-1/2$. The probability is the sum of those:
$$
p_n = C_1z_1^n+C_2z_2^n = C_1 + C_2\left(-\frac12\right)^n.
$$
Finally, we find constants from the initial conditions: $p_0=1$, $p_1=1/2$:
$$
p_n = \frac23+\frac13\left(-\frac12\right)^n
$$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you, why are you assuming $p_n=z^n$ and what are eigenvalues?

Comment: It's a standard procedure to solve [recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving)

Comment: Can I not be able to solve this by using the procedure which I've given in the comment?

Comment: It's possible. But it is way harder. What you are missing in your solution, is that the cases have different probability, because they consist of the different number of tosses. So you need to multiply $\binom 0k$ by $2^{-k}$, $\binom {1}{k-1}$ by $2^{-k-1}$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

N - Total Number of trials

$N = n_H+n_T$

$P(X = n_H) = {N\choose n_H}(\frac{1}{2})^{n_{H}}(\frac{1}{2})^{n_{T}}$

We also have $n_H+2n_T = n$

We have

When Case 1: $n_T =0 ;n_H = n$ and $N = n$

Case 2: $n_T =1; n_H = n-2$ and $N = n-1$

Case 3: $n_T =2 ;n_H = n-4$ and $N = n-2$

Case 4: $n_T =3 ;n_H = n-6$ and $N = n-3$

...

Case $\frac{n}{2}$: $n_T =\frac{n}{2} ;n_H = 0$ and $N = n-\frac{n}{2}$

At all instances we will have total number of points to be n.
Thus the required probability is

$\sum_{ case_i} P(X = n_H)$

Probability  $= \sum_{i=0}^{n/2} {(n-i)\choose(n-2i)}(\frac{1}{2})^{(n-2i)}(\frac{1}{2})^i$

Evaluated by Wolfram

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%2F2%7D+%7B(n-i)%5Cchoose(n-2i)%7D(1%2F2)%5E(n-2i)(1%2F2)%5Ei

Results value at different n

[image]

If you evaluate the formula for n = 2 and n = 3 to test if it comes out the same.

**I showed this cumbersome method to fine tune your line of thought.**